# create a new section for each row objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Right now this is working. I pull dynamic data from a server and populate each row with my results.  What i want to do is have a new section for each row.  I can't seem to figure it out, Any help would be great. thanks

```
#pragma mark - Table View
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"count the list %i",[self.dataController countOfList]);
    return [self.dataController countOfList];

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ShowDeals";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Deals *dealAtIndex = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:dealAtIndex.name];
    NSString *dollarSign = @"$";
    NSString *dealPrice = [dollarSign stringByAppendingString:dealAtIndex.price];

    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:dealPrice];

    return cell;
}
```

I want something like this, but it just populates the same date in the single row over and over.

```
#pragma mark - Table View
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.dataController countOfList];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"count the list %i",[self.dataController countOfList]);
    return 1;

}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ShowDeals";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Deals *dealAtIndex = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:dealAtIndex.name];
    NSString *dollarSign = @"$";
    NSString *dealPrice = [dollarSign stringByAppendingString:dealAtIndex.price];

    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:dealPrice];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Of course it does, check how you're fetching the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap the return values of

```
- numberOfSectionsInTableView:
```

and

```
- tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
```

(it seems you have already done this), and use

```
[self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.section]
                                             this  ^^^^^^^
```

instead of

```
[self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Awesome... I guess starring at a computer for 15 hours straight has its drawbacks.  I knew it was something right in front of my face.

Comment: @vinylDeveloper Most of the time, it's so simple :) Yesterday I had  a hard time figuring out why my custom reference counting system leaked memory so badly, when I realized I put a call to `free()` in a `#ifdef DEBUG`... >.<

Comment: nice. Half the time I have no idea what I'm doing anyway.  Just trial and a lot of erroeorr

Comment: @vinylDeveloper If you're hard-working enough, that will change over time to something more conscientious, for sure.

Comment: Ha.. lets hope so. I just can't get my head around objective c. But I like your style kid.